# I can't boot my VM(Ubuntu) after linux kernel build, install

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel

I am trying to study the Linux kernel using Virtual Box + Ubuntu
I googled how to download, build, and install the kernel version that I want and simply followed it

1. downloaded the Kernel file from kernel.org (which was in my case 5.4.92)
2. downloaded the tools that are used in kernel building
3. copied the .config file that the original kernel used
4. and followed the command
   make --> make modules --> make modules_install --> make install
5. update-initramfs and update-grub (I read somewhere that 'make install' does all this but just in case...)
6. Finally I rebooted the VM

My problem is after all this procedure 'uname -a' showed the original kernel
(which was 5.8.0-40-generic, I used Ubuntu 20.4)
And after some research, I found out how to use the Grub, and tried to boot the 5.4.92 version manually. But It showed a blank screen and stopped. (like the picture)

[The State after i manually tried to boot the new kernel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JXEv.png)

I am aware that after I succeed in this procedure I could change some codes in the kernel file --> re-build it --> and install it
But i am stuck at the first  step...It would be really helpful if anyone could give me some hint!!

Thank you in advance
p.s if there are additional information needed to help me please inform me

Comment: could you elaborate on how you tried to boot manually? If i understood correctly you were able to boot and then after attempting to boot manually it goes black. Sounds like the issue happened when you made modifications somewhere related to grub.

Comment: I pressed the shift while booting leading me able to select one of the kernels installed in my VM, and after I chose the newly installed one, it went black.
The only modifications that i did with grub was these two lines
$ sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.4.92
$ sudo update-grub
could you tell me what part should i look into?